# como fazer um texto se ajustar ao tamanho da tela tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Estou fazendo uma aplicação no tkinter e preciso que o texto digitado em um único Label se ajuste ao tamanho da janela, porque se não eu tenho que ficar usando quebra de linha.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
from tkinter import *
janela1 = Tk()
janela1.title("INTRODUÇÃO")
janela1.geometry("750x600+200+50")
lb2 = Label(janela1, text="\n\nSe está aqui, é porque certamente gostaria de aprender a programar,\n ou precisa de ajuda em algum assunto básico :)\n\nPrimeiramente gostaríamos de te contar um pouco sobre a nossa iniciativa!!", font="Arial 12", bg='light blue').pack()
lb3 = Label(janela1, text="\n\nO     objetivo deste 'curso' é lhe ensinar o básico sobre programação utilizando a linguagem python.\nAo final dele você deve ser capaz de fazer xxxxxxx", font="Arial 12", bg="light blue").pack()

janela1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Coloca o código que tens, pelo menos a parte relevante sff

Comment: nao uses isto, edita a tua pergunta sff, por baixo tens aí o link para editares. Aqui é reservado para cometários

Comment: é horrivel colocar código aqui AAAAAAAAAAAAAAH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando o argumento `wraplength` consegues fazer com que o texto dentro do Label tenha uma dimensão específica, coloquei a mesma dimensão da janela:

```
from tkinter import *

win_width, win_height = 750, 600
janela1 = Tk()
janela1.title("INTRODUÇÃO")
janela1.geometry('{}x{}'.format(win_width, win_height))
lb2 = Label(janela1, wraplength=win_width, text="Se está aqui, é porque certamente gostaria de aprender a programar, ou precisa de ajuda em algum assunto básico :) Primeiramente gostaríamos de te contar um pouco sobre a nossa iniciativa!!", font="Arial 12", bg='light blue').pack()
lb3 = Label(janela1, pady=20, wraplength=win_width, text="O     objetivo deste 'curso' é lhe ensinar o básico sobre programação utilizando a linguagem python. Ao final dele você deve ser capaz de fazer xxxxxxx", font="Arial 12", bg="light blue").pack()

janela1.mainloop()
```

Também fiz uma margem (`pady`) entre o texto de baixo e o de cima

Comment: Muito Obrigada <3